# Blank screen after updating to 19.10

Tags: upgrade, 19.10

I just upgraded my wife’s Dell Latitude E6510 from 19.04 to 19.10. It would not shutdown after the update. She eventually turned the laptop off using the power key, and now when she tries to turn it back on there is merely a blank purple screen. None of the other helpful comments about dealing with a blank screen seem to apply here, since alt-f1-12 does nothing, and I see no data of any kind. It’s just a purple screen.

Is this fixable or is the workstation bricked?

Comment: Rather than power off, a better strategy is to use [magic] SysRq keys to ensure a valid shutdown (ie. REISUB).  I mention magic as i find it helpful to search online (wikipedia article calls it magic sysrq) to get a refresher of the keystrokes using a phone etc.  In your case; I'd boot a 'live' system, and `fsck` (file system check) your partitions.  Then I'd boot and try and login to text terminal only,  (I'd check sources or `sudo apt update`) then continue `apt full-upgrade` until it completes & no more updates are found. Then reboot & I'd expect it to login normally.